# Unable to locate Spring XML Schema Namespace Exception for the Spring Data JPA (only while deploying!)

Tags: spring, tomcat, namespaces, dependencies, spring-data-jpa

I have two Spring-Maven Projects. First one is for the **backend** (SpringDataJpa Repositories and Service Classes). It runs standalone (JUnits) without problem.

The second one is for the **frontend** (SpringMVC), and this project defines the backend as a required project on the build path. Also in the Deployment assembly properties, I have added the backend project (WEB-INF/lib/Backend.jar), so it will be deployed too (Actually should not it be added here automatically when i define the backend as a dependency?)..

Anyway, my main problem is this exception i get when i deploy the frontend project.

```
Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
```

this exception occurs in the backend file "spring-jpa.cfg.xml" which looks like:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <jpa:repositories base-package="acn.spring.backend.springDataJpa" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

In Backend-POM defined dependencies: all kinds of spring dependencies (3.2.4) and spring data jpa (1.4.1)
In Frontend-POM defined dependencies: spring-mvc (3.2.4)

First i thought that i should define the spring data jpa dependencies also in the frontend (although the frontend project does not have a direct dependency). It did not change anything.

Secondly in the build path properties of the backend, in the order export tab, i choose the maven dependencies, so it may export the dependencies of the backend to the dependent frontend project. It did not change also anything..

I dont understand how this namespace can be found while running backend standalone, but not under **tomcat**. I would appreciate any ideas.

This is the backend POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SpringBusiness</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBusiness</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Shared version number properties -->
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Core utilities used by other modules. Define this if you use Spring 
            Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Expression Language (depends on spring-core) Define this if you use 
            Spring Expression APIs (org.springframework.expression.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core) Define 
            this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, 
            spring-beans) Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, 
            spring-beans) This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection 
            Container and is generally always defined -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, 
            Quartz, and Freemarker integration Define this if you need any of these integrations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-aop, spring-context) Define this if you use Spring Transactions or 
            DAO Exception Hierarchy (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, 
            spring-tx) Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA and 
            iBatis. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx) 
            Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, 
            JiBX, Castor, XStream, and XML Beans. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-context) Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Support for testing Spring applications with tools such as JUnit and 
            TestNG This artifact is generally always defined with a 'test' scope for 
            the integration testing framework and unit testing stubs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And this is the frontend POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>acn.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringShop</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <org.springframework.security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is my application-context.xml in the backend:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation=
    "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Database Access -->
    <import resource="data-source.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring-jpa.cfg.xml"/>

    <!-- Middle Layer -->
    <import resource="aop-context.xml"/>
    <import resource="transaction-context.xml"/>
    <import resource="service-context.xml"/>

</beans>
```

This is the web.xml of the fronted, where i define the application context as a dependency (So i don't define the spring-jpa.cfg.xml again):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SpringShop</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- needed for ContextLoaderListener -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml, /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
....
```

Web Deployment Assembly for the Frontend: (SpringBusiness is the name of the backend project)

[image]

**EDIT: When I define all my dependencies (which are actually used just from the backend) also in the frontend pom, i dont get the exception. What is the correct way of doing this? It does not make any sense to define all the dependencies again, since the backend jar is already defined in the deployment assembly of the frontend..**

Comment: Please show your poms or at least your dependencies therein. Also, are you importing spring-jpa.cfg.xml in your frontend project's spring xml configs?? That's the only way I can see that your frontend project would even care about the content of that file and try to parse it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. I should have defined the dependency (backend->frontend) not in eclipse build path preferences, but in pom. Now this is the situation for the frontend project:

**Web Deployment Assembly does not include the backend project:**

[image]

**Build path does not include the backend either:**

[image]

But the frontend pom defines a dependency on the backend.jar. Now i build the backend by "mvn clean install", the jar of the backend has been produced and put into the local maven repository. So the frontend project can use it. Even under tomcat.

Comment: This is precisely what I said in my answer, but if you want to accept it as your own, that's your prerogative.

Comment: Sorry for that. But i did not conclude this from your comments. Now when i read you saying "You should declare a dependency on the backend project using maven.." or "If you are using maven, you need to make a <dependency> on the backend project.." i understand you meant this in an indirect way (indirect because you used 'using maven' instead of 'placing a dependency section in pom.xml'). But it was little confusing for me since i should have defined the <dependency> in frontend, not in backend. Thank you very much for your help though. I already mark your answer as useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Complete Re-edit**

"I have added the backend project (WEB-INF/lib/Backend.jar)"

You are not getting the full use of maven by doing this. You should declare a dependency on the backend project using maven in order for maven to pull in all of the backend project's dependencies. What is happening right now is that you are making yourself dependent on the Backend.jar but NOT its dependencies, which means the spring jar containing the necessary namespace handler is NOT in your classpath.

Comment: Since my frontend does not have any application context (just web.xml, servlet.xmls and some JSPs etc..) this should not solve my problem. I don’t understand your aim telling “if you intend to load only the context for the frontend..” The backend project is just there to be used from the frontend. And application context of the backend has everything (Beans for the services etc.) what the frontend exactly needs.

Comment: Ah from your description it sounded like you did NOT want to load the backend's application-context.xml...in which case my assumption was that you were accidentally doing so. Honestly, though, from looking at your dependencies, I don't even see a dependency on backend from frontend, so I would assume you're doing something completely non-standard to include the backend project in your frontend war.

Comment: I do not have any dependency on backend from frontent. I should not have to and I do not want to..

Comment: But you said you want to use the application-context.xml that's provided by the backend project... ???

"The second one is for the frontend (SpringMVC), and this project defines the backend as a required project on the build path."

Actually here is your problem:

"I have added the backend project (WEB-INF/lib/Backend.jar)"

This is the non-standard bit I suspected. If you are using maven, you need to make a <dependency> on the backend project or else you will not get all of the backend's dependencies. There's no way for your frontend to know all the dependencies it needs to run properly.

Comment: Firstly thank you very much for your help. I think we just have a language issue here :) For me these are all same: "using the application-context.xml that's provided by the backend project" - "frontend (SpringMVC) defines the backend as a required project" - "not having any dependency on backend from frontend, but having on frontend from backend." Just like a standard project, frontend is working by calling services from backend.. For your last editing, i can tell you that, in order to make the frontend dependent on the backend.. (to be continued..)

Comment: I have added the backend project as a required project on the build path of the frontend project (frontend requires backend). So until now you have right telling "What is happening right now is that you are making yourself dependent on the Backend.jar but NOT its dependencies". But i also go to build path properties of the BACKEND, on the "order and export" tab, i mark the maven dependencies to be exported. So these should contribute to dependent projects (frontend). Or?

Comment: No, "Order and Export" have nothing to do with Maven or your deployment. I assume you are using Eclipse? If so, that is useful only in an Eclipse environment. When you deploy, you need to do a build using Maven to make sure all dependencies are pulled into your war.

Comment: Ok. What I forgot to write in my last comment is -but you saw this in my question description above anyway- I also add the backend project to the Deployment Assembly of the frontend, so the Backend.jar should be added to WEB-INF/lib. And in this Backend.jar i have all my dependencies which are used by backend right? (I have added a pic of web deployment assembly to the end of my question.)